# Detect ClickOnce program's server?

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I'm deploying a ClickOnce application. I need to find a way to detect from which server the application was downloaded and installed from - because the application checks for updates on launch, I know that somewhere it knows the "parent" server - can I get at that value somehow?

I need this value because the installed program needs to access services on the server that it was installed from - but that server can change depending on the deployment environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment
```

(specifically, `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation`) to access the ClickOnce properties associated with the running instance.

Note that if you're debugging, these won't be available - you can do an

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
```

To test if you're running the application through the ClickOnce deployment.

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.activationuri.aspx)